# How to set cron job periodically in magento?

Tags: cron, magento2.2.6, crontab

I have below cron job code. Currently, it is running for every 30 minutes.

```
<job name="customer_details" instance="my_file_name" method="my_method">
  <schedule>*/30 * * * *</schedule>
</job>
```

I want my cron job should run daily at 10:30 PM to generate the csv related to customer details based on some criteria.

What should be the value inside `<schedule> * * * * * </schedule>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

minute hour day month day-of-the-week

So 10:30pm would be:

```
<schedule>30 22 * * *</schedule>
```

Answer (score 3):

Next time you want to check what value i should add on the cron schedule , take a look at this magical cron expressions finder.[Crontab Guru Link](https://crontab.guru/#30_22_*_*_*)
[image]